# JSF retrieve value of selectitems

Tags: jsf

I have a selectonemenu and select items are object in the database.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.country}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.name}" itemValue="#{c.name}"/>
```

Is it possible that i can set the population of country c in a hidden field like for example:

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{c.population}"></h:inputHidden>
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? what is your logic?

Comment: Please take a step back and tell about the problem for which you thought that this would be the solution. Then we can tell about the right approach.

Comment: Basically im trying to retrieve the property population from country c when I selects the country from the select one menu and store population value in a hidden input